# Devise route not respected on Devise view pages

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have implemented devise and set up the routes to prettyify the urls as so (in the routes file):

```
devise_scope :user do
    get "/login" => "devise/sessions#new"
    get "/logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy"
    get "/register" => "devise/registrations#new"
end
```

I have global menu in my application.html.erb file, however, which now inserts devise/controller/action on every link that is on the login or register pages, such as

```
<%= link_to "Upload Video", {:controller => "videos", :action => "new"} %>
```

becomes devise/videos/new

Any ideas on how to fix this? I can hack around it but I'm pretty sure it is a simple fix.

Cheers,

s

Answer (score 0):

Take out the `devise_scope` and try something like this:

```
  devise_for  :users, 
              :controllers => {:registrations => 'devise/registrations', :sessions => 'devise/sessions'}, 
              :path => '/',
              :path_names => {:sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout'}
```